# What is the difference between these two versions of code?

Tags: c++, c++11, most-vexing-parse

This code causes compilation error (most vexing parse)

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
        int a;
public:
        A(int x) :a(x) {}
};

class B {
public:
        B(const A& obj) { std::cout << "B\n";}
        void foo() {std::cout << "foo\n";}
};

int main()
{
        int test = 20;
        B var(A(test));      //most vexing parse
        var.foo();
        return 0;
}
```

But if I pass `20` instead of `test` (`A(20)` instead of `A(test)`), there is no compilation error.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
        int a;
public:
        A(int x) :a(x) {}
};

class B {
public:
        B(const A& obj) { std::cout << "B\n";}
        void foo() {std::cout << "foo\n";}
};

int main()
{
        int test = 20;
        //B var(A(test));
        B var(A(20));            //ok works fine
        var.foo();
        return 0;
}
```

Why is this not considered as most vexing parse? What is the difference between these two code versions?

Comment: This is basically the example [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse#Example_with_functions). The second case is not vexing because `20` cannot be a variabl ename.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A variable can be defined like

```
type(name)
```

Because of that

```
B var(A(test));
```

declares a function named `var` that returns a `B` and takes an `A` named `test`.  In

```
B var(A(20));
```

if you tried to do the same thing, the `A` parameter would be called `20`, which is not a valid variable name.  Since it cannot be the name of a variable we know it is a value and instead we are constructing a variable named `var` of type `B` with the value of `A(20)`.

Answer (score 5):

The most-vexing-parse issue is a problem of grammar, not semantics. Grammatically, `A(test)` boils down to `identifier : OPEN_PAREN : identifier : CLOSE_PAREN`. In context, this is ambiguous because the second identifier could be a variable name or a typename. The compiler has to pick a way of interpreting this sequence of tokens, and neither one is incorrect.

By contrast, `A(20)` boils down to `identifier : OPEN_PAREN : integer_literal : CLOSE_PAREN`. An integer literal cannot be interpreted as an identifier, so there is no way to interpret it as a typename. It must therefore be parsed as an expression which initializes an object of type `A`.